# LCP Generation Error

Tags: r, gis, qgis

I've been trying to generate an LCP network between various points. I've had some success with some of my data sets but other sets cause an error to occur whenever I try to run the function. The data all follows the same format and reside in the same CRS so I don't understand what the issue is. I've tried a few workarounds but nothing has taken so far. I've included the basic script I use.

```
library(rgdal)
library(gdistance)
TRI<-raster("pathway.tif")
points<-readOGR("pathway.shp")
cost<-transition(TRI,sum,8)
LCP<-shortestPath(cost,points[1,],points[-1,],output="SpatialLines")
```

These arguments have worked for some parts of my dataset, but several of them show the following error message after I input the last line above and I'm not sure what the fix is as I'm pretty new to R:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
invalid class “SpatialLines” object: bbox should never contain infinite values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .Call("R_igraph_get_shortest_paths", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph,  :
 At structural_properties.c:4517 :Couldn't reach some vertices
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reproducible example. It seems that you are creating some unconnected components in your TransitionLayer. Check the gdistance vignette for ways to avoid and detect this. See page 8 of https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i13